# Can TFS 2018 artifact maven support upstream repo?

Tags: maven, tfs

My expectation:

1. maven build tasks search dependency jars from TFS local repo
2. if dependency jars cannot be found in local TFS repo, TFS pulls dependency jars from maven central and save a copy in local
3. if there are new versions of dependency jars, how TFS knows it and automatically pulls the new versions to local repository

Comment: A Maven build searches in a repository manager and never in a version control tool like TFS ...and should never commit jars into your version control. Better use things like a repository manage to handle them...

Comment: Thanks  khmarbaise...  en, sorry I may mislead you. I am trying to say how to use  the TFS artifacts instead of the maven central repository.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to say how to use the TFS artifacts instead of the maven central repository in the maven build process. Thanks